# Upload binary file as image to stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, images, rules

I am having an idea, and I would like to know if it is complied with Stack Exchange sites license.

I want to hide a file (binary file) withing an image, and upload the image to Stack Overflow.

I can post a script that converts the image back to the original file.

I created a proof of concept using the following Matlab code:

```
I = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgGer.png');
f = fopen('PaddedBinFile.zip', 'w');
fwrite(f, I, 'uint8');
fclose(f);
```

The code downloads the image, and saves image as data to a file named: `PaddedBinFile.zip`.

The password for the zip file is: `stackoverflow`

The following image hides an encrypted zip file:
[image]

Am I breaking rules here?

Comment: We don't have a specific rule about this, but the purpose of the image hosting is to host *images* for the site. If you're asking a question about [stenography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography), this might be fine. If you're using it to store random data for use elsewhere, that would be abusive. Using it as a general-purpose post attachment mechanism is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Did you try to download that image again and do a filecompare? Because the last time I tried that the files differed so much that they can't be unzipped. Just as your example. That is no longer a valid zip file for me after downloading.

Comment: @rene sure, I am just getting a warning message "There are some data after the end of the payload data". I can avoid that warning with some minor effort. The key factor is to upload the image using uncompressed format (like `png`) and not as `jpg`.

Comment: @JeremyBanks The main purpose is stenography. From time to time, when asking, or answering a question users need to post a binary file. In Matlab specifically, there is always a problem with `fig` files, created by a tool called [guide](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-gui.html). I thought about a mechanism for posting `fig` files.

Comment: IMHO, if a question requires the transfer of a binary, it is inappropriate for SO. I don't know whether that gunge above is illegal porn, a copyrighted image or a pic of your cat.  Furthermore, I would certainly not waste time finding out by unzipping it:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, [Mathematica](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/new-se-tools-formerly-known-as-se-uploader) uses this technique via an add-on to allow users to attach code and other Mathematica stuff. See: https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools/blob/master/README.md

Granted, that's Mathematica, not Matlab. But presumably what's good for the goose is good for the goose's weird cousin.

Obviously if you used this technique to post something harmful or offensive this would be frowned upon, just as posting images that are themselves offensive is frowned upon.

Answer (score -6):

I think that will not break a rule unless there is something very offensive in the decoded message.

Comment: Well, I mean… that's partly what Meta questions are *for* is determining whether such rules exist implicitly, or need to be hashed out.